# install pip package python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

```
#i am trying install pip package on python version 3.7.1 and i tried:
 curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py #first command
 python get-pip.py #second command
```

## and the i have exception about the range of list specifically:

```
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

## the exception is:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ΦΩΤΗΣ ΣΤΑΥΡΙΑΝΟΣ\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjpbaflws\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\Users\ΦΩΤΗΣ ΣΤΑΥΡΙΑΝΟΣ\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjpbaflws\pip.zip\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
File "C:\Users\ΦΩΤΗΣ ΣΤΑΥΡΙΑΝΟΣ\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjpbaflws\pip.zip\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
File "C:\Users\ΦΩΤΗΣ ΣΤΑΥΡΙΑΝΟΣ\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjpbaflws\pip.zip\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 259, in _resolve_one
dist = abstract_dist.dist(self.finder)
File "C:\Users\ΦΩΤΗΣ ΣΤΑΥΡΙΑΝΟΣ\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjpbaflws\pip.zip\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 77, in dist
self.req.source_dir))[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Are you trying to install a package through `pip` or the `pip` itself? Because in Python 3.4 and after, this package comes with the installation so you don't need to install it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Oh no, this seems like a python/windows problem with unicode in the path. Unfortunately choosing username in greek(or basically anything non-english) can break some stuff...

You should try using `python3 -m "ensurepip"`, this is the new approved way to get pip installed, AFAIK. May be they fixed it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3.7.1 and have installed Python from python.org PIP should already be installed. Maybe try running a few pip commands to check if that is the case?

Source: The first pharagraph of https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/